# When do you or don't bet the river headsup and you last to act?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, no-limit

When do you bet the river heads-up when you're last to act, the villain checks to you, and you feel that you have the winning hand?  Rephrase, under what situations do you bet the river after your one and only opponent checks to you and you are pretty sure you have the best hand?

Do you always bet here since you feel like you have the best hand?  If not, can you detail some situations where you would not bet here?

I have formulated a solution in my mind to this situation after watching many poker vlog videos and read some more about "modern" poker playing.  I'd like to see some others' views on this topic.

Comment: How often does your opponent sandbag?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica This sounds like a consideration. It could be that the opponent is sandbagging or a novice player who doesn't know how to value bet, therefore the only bet the river with the nuts are a very very strong hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most factor is : frequency and combination.

1. Live game is very different to online game. (tells are very important).
2. Take a note in any showdown when opponent check on the river and see type of point have on river (middle value? (little-middle pair?) ? Top pair bad kicker? and so on ..
3. When you see how your opponent play in this situation(check on the river) u try to adjust. If opponent check middle value, try to bet big and see her reaction. and try to adjust. If opponent show often no point(two random card), we attack his check on the river ..
   and so on.
4. If your opponent is good, have a mix value on the check when face check :
   bottom value (low pair), middle value (mid pair , second pair, top pair with bad kiker ), top value (strong point like flush or straight) ... We need the right ones frequency with a right combos.

Right combos is a blocker . For example in a texture Q56 rainbow, turn 8 river 7
if opponent check , A right bluff combination is  some ,KT,TJ, etc.. because block the probabily of opponent have 9T, 99 and TT (KT blokers KQ opponent combos but have a show down value..it's only an example)..

When u bluff take in mind how opponent call after check on the river and try to adjust.

Take in mind that amateur players over estimate their point and over call a lot.